# Create a DMG file with Installer

Tags: swift, macos, dmg

Hi i have created a dmg file. with the command.

`hdiutil create -format UDZO -srcfolder folder_to_compress archive_name.dmg`

The structure of the DMG is the following

```
--Install.app
--payloads
----Application.app
----com.application.helper.plist
```

I have created and Install.app with whom i can install the application as well as the helper file. When clicking on the installer Apple asks me to Install the Install file and not to launch it from disk image. 
Can i prevent this somehow? Adobe also has an Install.app but apple is not asking. I checked the plist files but i could not find something indication that the application should be launched from disk image.

[image: Prompt from apple]

Comment: Please provide some screenshots.

Comment: Just added the screenshot